# VBA to List SQL connections and their properties within multi sheet Excel workbooks

Tags: sql, database, excel, vba, connection

I have inherited a number of complex Excel multi worksheet workbooks with a number of different SQL data connections. Some are password protected, some have a connection file, some refresh data on opening etc.
I need to document and check these. I'd prefer to do this programmatically rather than trawl through each connection manually using the "Connections" dialogue.
Is there a means of iterating through each worksheet and providing a list of the various "Connection Properties" available in the "Usage" and "Definition" tabs?
I am fairly proficient in VBA but cannot figure this one out!

The only starting code I have so far is

```
Private Sub cmd_TestIt_Click()<br>
 Dim wb As Workbook<br>
 Dim wks As Worksheet
 Dim pt As PivotTable
 Dim pc As PivotCache

 Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
 For Each wks In Worksheets
     For Each pt In wks.PivotTables
         Set pc = wb.PivotCaches(pt.CacheIndex)
         mystring = "Data Range : " & pc.SourceData
         MsgBox mystring
  Next
Next
End Sub
```

This gives me the data connection but I really need the properties of that data connection
--21/08/2015 ---
OK. I'm part the way there. I have code that works but it is clunky.
Cmd_testit works, but there should be some method of adding a For .. Each for the Connection items.As it is I can only do one connection.

```
Private Sub cmd_TestIt_Click()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim splitz() As String
Dim j As Integer
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

mystring = mystring + "Refresh on Open=" +    CStr(wb.Connections.item(1).OLEDBConnection.RefreshOnFileOpen) + ";"
mystring = mystring + "Save Password=" + CStr(wb.Connections.item(1).OLEDBConnection.SavePassword) + ";"
mystring = mystring + "Connection file=" +    wb.Connections.item(1).OLEDBConnection.SourceConnectionFile
mystring = mystring + wb.Connections.item(1).OLEDBConnection.Connection
splitz = Split(mystring, ";")
mystring = ""
For j = 0 To UBound(splitz)
    mystring = mystring + splitz(j) + vbCrLf
Next
MsgBox mystring
End Sub
```

I'm trying this out with "Test2" but cannot find the magic combination to make this work.

```
Private Sub Test2_Click()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim splitz() As String
Dim j As Integer
Dim item As Items
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
For Each item In wb.Connections
    mystring = mystring + "Refresh on Open=" + CStr(item.OLEDBConnection.RefreshOnFileOpen) + ";"
    mystring = mystring + "Save Password=" +   CStr(item.OLEDBConnection.SavePassword) + ";"
    mystring = mystring + "Connection file=" + item.OLEDBConnection.SourceConnectionFile
    mystring = mystring + item.OLEDBConnection.Connection
    splitz = Split(mystring, ";")
    mystring = ""
    For j = 0 To UBound(splitz)
        mystring = mystring + splitz(j) + vbCrLf
   Next
   MsgBox mystring
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! As you may have skipped the intro for this site: “Code this for me” questions are generally frowned upon around here, however, we’d love to help you learn! If you could, please post any code you have already tried. For further information on posting a question, you might want to have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cracked it! Seems that this works if I don't define item as Items!
I'm now going to replace the MsgBox with an output to file.
I'll then open the file in Notepad!
Please let me know if there is a better way of doing this!

```
Private Sub Test2_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim splitz() As String
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim item
    Dim StrCon As String
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    For Each item In wb.Connections
        StrCon = ""
        StrCon = "Refresh on Open=" +     CStr(item.OLEDBConnection.RefreshOnFileOpen) + ";"
        StrCon = StrCon + "Save Password=" + CStr(item.OLEDBConnection.SavePassword) + ";"
        StrCon = StrCon + "Connection file=" + item.OLEDBConnection.SourceConnectionFile + ";"
        StrCon = StrCon + item.OLEDBConnection.Connection
        splitz = Split(StrCon, ";")
        StrCon = ""
        For j = 0 To UBound(splitz)
            StrCon = StrCon + splitz(j) + vbCrLf
        Next
        MsgBox StrCon
    Next
End Sub
```